# Vaadin one to many and Grid binding.Property not found

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

There is the Customer entity which has a one to many relationship to entity Address,so there is a `List<Address>` getAddress in Customer.Address has an Email field.

So for instance to get an email from the first customer you do customer.getAddress.get(0).getEmail

When I bind to a Customer.class grid,setColumns("customerid","address.email") it throws an exception Property not found.

If I do addColumn(customer->customer.getAddress.get(0).get email).setHeader(email) it does display the email.

But that's for the first customer.How to do the same for all customers?

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you expected to happen. That the grid automatically shows a row for each address of each customer? That's not how it works. If you bind a list of customers, grid will display one row per customer. If you want to display each address of each customer, then map your data into a new bean containing data for a single customer and a single address. Then bind the grid to that bean. Alternatively check out tree grid, which can display hierarchical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default presentation for a `List` is `toString()`. You need to create a Renderer to display the list nicely. For better performance you can create a [LitRenderer](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/grid/flow/#using-lit-renderers). See also the Lit documentation for [repeating templates](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/lists/#repeating-templates-with-map).

```
grid.addColumn(LitRenderer.<Customer>of("""
        ${item.address.map((adr) => 
            html`<span>${adr.email}</span><br />`
        )}
        """).withProperty("address", Customer::getAddress));
```

Would look like this:

[image]

Maybe replace the `span` element with `<a href="mailto:${adr.email}">${adr.email}</a>` for better UX.

Comment: `There is no support for nested properties.` - I don't think that's true. AFAIK nested properties are supported like this. If the `address` property was not a list, this should probably work

Comment: You are right, I tested it.